# C read big matrix from input file

Tags: c, matrix, binary, fwrite, fread

Im trying to read a 40000x40000 boolean (binary) matrix from a input file and store it in a variable. After I store it in the variable, I want to write it to a file. However, with the code I wrote it takes more than a hour. Can someone help me out? I think im doing something wrong.

Code

```
void get_grid_values_file(bool *grid, int n, int m, char *input_filename){
    FILE *in_file;
    in_file = fopen(input_filename, "r");  
    char buffer[1]; 
    bool search = true;
    int k=0;
    while(search){
       fseek(in_file, k, SEEK_SET);
       fread(buffer, 1, 1, in_file); 
        if(*buffer == '\n')
            search = false;
        k++;         
    }
    int i,j;    
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
           fseek(in_file, k, SEEK_SET);
           fread(buffer, 1, 1, in_file);  
           *((grid+i*m) + j) = atof(buffer);   
           k+=2;
        }
    }
    fclose(in_file);
}

void set_grid_values_file(bool *grid, int n, int m, char *output_filename){
    FILE *out_file;
    out_file = fopen(output_filename, "w"); 
    char buffer[1] = " "; 
    //Set n,m and spaces
    int length_n= (int) (log10 (abs (n))) + 1;
    char char_n[length_n];
    sprintf(char_n, "%d", n);
    fseek(out_file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite (char_n, length_n, 1, out_file);
    fseek(out_file, length_n, SEEK_SET); 
    fwrite (" ", 1, 1, out_file);      
    int length_m= (int) (log10 (abs (m))) + 1;
    char char_m[length_m];
    sprintf(char_m, "%d", m);
    fseek(out_file, length_n+1, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite (char_m, length_m, 1, out_file);
    fseek(out_file, length_n+1+length_m, SEEK_SET);
    fwrite ("\n", sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
    //Set grid
    int i,j;
    int k =length_n + length_m + 2;
    for(i=0; i<n; i++){
        for(j=0; j<m; j++){
           fseek(out_file, k, SEEK_SET);           
           buffer[0] = (*((grid+i*m) + j) == true ? '1' : '0');
           fwrite (buffer, 1, 1, out_file);    
           k++;
           fseek(out_file, k, SEEK_SET); 
           fwrite (" ", 1, 1, out_file);
           k++; 
        }
        fseek(out_file, k, SEEK_SET);
        fwrite ("\n", sizeof(char), 1, out_file);
        k++;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *input_filename = "gen0_40kx40k.in";
    char *output_filename = "gol_output.out";
    int n = 40000;
    int m = 40000;


    bool *grid = (bool *)malloc(n*m*sizeof(bool));
    //Read
    get_grid_values_file((bool *)grid, n, m, input_filename);

    //Write
    set_grid_values_file((bool *)grid, n, m, output_filename);

    return 0;
}
```

Input format, the first line contains the dem of the 2d matrix: 
20 20
1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 
0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 
1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 
1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 
1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0
0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1
1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1

Comment: That's 1.6 billion binary values, which you're reading/writing as ASCII bytes and you're processing them one value at a time. The hour-plus time doesn't surprise me at all. Do you have control over the file format? Perhaps you could make it binary and process it a word at a time, handling several bits before hitting the file system. Or even if it's ASCII, deal with it a line at a time in an array. But hitting the file system for every cell is going to take a very long time.

Comment: How are you getting `40000x40000` from `"input format, the first line contains the dem of the 2d matrix"` which has `20 20` as the first line?

Comment: Does your "binary" `input_filename` really have spaces in it? Or is the format as shown above, just representative of the values in the file? Binary files are generally not stored with `spaces` or `newlines`. Those are formatted "text" file contents. The answer to this question, determines what you need to do to input your data, and then output your data. Either way, there is no need for a 2D array, Just `fread` (or `mmap`, if available) the file into a buffer and write it out however you wish. That will be orders of magnitude faster than what you are doing.

Comment: @lurker well I just have to set the grid array variable by the given file.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The example shown is the 20x20 matrix (showed on the first line). The file which im trying to handle would have 40000 40000 on the first line. And yes it has spaces and new lines in it, after I parse the data I really need to store the values in the boolean 2d array since I am going to do some calculations on it.

Comment: OK, recommendation would be to ditch `bool`, you are not buying any space savings, and if you are not going to use `bits` instead of `bytes`, you may even be costing yourself memory, because there is no guarantee that `bool` uses the smallest storage size. (there are compiler options for some OS's to insure this)

Answer (score 0):

Read larger chunks from the input file - not every char as a separate call. Eg a complete row of your matrix at once.

Why do you use in the inner loop of `set_grid_values_file` two `fwrite` calls. Better to combine them:

```
char buffer[2] = "  ";
for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    int base = grid+i*m;
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){
        fseek(out_file, k, SEEK_SET);           
        buffer[0] = (*(base + j) ? '1' : '0');
        fwrite (buffer, 1, 2, out_file);    
        k+=2; 
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest removing the calls to `fseek`.

```
while(search){

   // Make sure the read is successful. Otherwise, break out of the loop.
   if ( fread(buffer, 1, 1, in_file) != 1 )
   {
      break;
   } 

   if(*buffer == '\n')
       search = false;
   k++;         
}
int i,j;    

// Rewind the file
fseek(in_file, 0, SEEK_SET);

for(i=0; i<n; i++){
    for(j=0; j<m; j++){

      // Make sure the read is successful. Otherwise, break out of the loop.
      if ( fread(buffer, 1, 1, in_file) != 1 )
      {
         break;
      } 

      *((grid+i*m) + j) = atof(buffer);   
      k+=2;
    }
}
```

Also `atof(buffer)` is a problem when `buffer` has only one element in it. Use at least a two element array.

```
char buffer[2] = {0};
```

Answer (score 0):

This is about the simplest(and possibly the fastest) method.

- stdio is buffered, `getc()` is most probably a macro
- function calls are costly (they trash the instruction pipeline and cache) ; you use 1seek+1fread per boolean bit read.
- you dont need to seek the file; just read it sequentially and put the values at the correct{row,col} positions.
- setting and testing an indicator variable (your `search`) is a waste of time (often taught in Pascal and Java classes...) ;instead: just jump out of the loop (or continue)
- I am assuming an ASCII file with spaces between the values, but without the{nrow,ncol} at the top (the{n,m}values are supplied as function arguments)

---

```
void get_grid_values_file(bool *grid, int n, int m, char *input_filename)
{
unsigned col,row;
FILE * fp;

fp= fopen (input_filename, "r" );
if(!fp)return;

for(row=col=0; ; ) {
        int ch;
        ch=getc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF)break;
        if (ch < '0' || ch > '1') continue;

        grid[row*m+col++] = (ch == '0') ? False :True;
        if (col == m) {col=0; row++; }
        if (row == n) break;
        }
fclose(fp);
return;
}
```